# AngularJS : array of objects in CookiesStore

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Is there a method to save, read and modify an array of objects in the cookieStore with angularJs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is not. You have to do the array modifications by yourself and store the array back to the cookieStore:

```
$cookieStore.put('key', []);
var array = $cookieStore.get('key');
array.push('value');
$cookieStore.put('key', array);
```

Comment: to get this array in other page how I can it?

Comment: what did you mean with "page". the cookieStore is bound to your origin - so your full SPA have access to this information

Comment: I would be interested if anyone has developed an angularjs/cookiestore module that would automatically reload (or create) a property on a scope and save it whenever the model changes.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you check out this module that allows you to easily use local storage or cookie storage and bind it to your scope:

http://ngmodules.org/modules/angularLocalStorage

Example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Y1mrNVRkInCItqvZXtto?p=preview

```
var eS = angular.module('exampleStore', ['localStorage']);

  eS.controller('MainCtrl',['$scope','$store',function($scope, $store) {
      $store.bind($scope, 'test', 'Some Default Text');

      $scope.clearTest = function(){ 
          $store.remove('test'); 
      };
  }]);
```